# Ubuntu: Apache access forbidden error

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, virtualhost, http-status-code-403, forbidden

I've been experiencing a problem with my virtual hosts, I don't understand why apache looks for `/home/*` directory if my virtualhosts' directory is somewhere else?

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
/home/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

Sultan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't. You must have this somewhere in your Apache configuration.

Or you have a softlink somewhere in your webdirectory/code to your home account.

Comment: Actually my virtualhosts are stored in my /home/www/hostsdirectory does it affect somehow?

Comment: Well it seems that your webroot is then considered as 
/home/* as you said..

Apache by default looks in "every" directory for a .htaccess file..
You should probably look at you base document root in your httpd.conf file..
Also do you have any idea which vhosts is requesting your /home/.htaccess??

Comment: I've about 10 virtual hosts and requests on allof them give the same result

Comment: Very strange..
Make sure your vhosts are having the document root set properly

/home/www/website.com/


And check your code..
your might be referencing..

../../../../image.jpeg
or 
/home/www/website.com/../../image.jpeg

Comment: For sure I'd say this happens even if I setup some example.com with some "hello world" message within index file

Comment: Basically it sounds like your apache is not configured correctly..

and you have build your vhosts on top of this..

Try your hello world.. see what happens :D

Answer (score 1):

755 ist the answer, as all your files have to be readable by railo (which is actually not the same user as your Apache).

Answer (score 0):

Permissions on `/home` may not allow apache to read the directory appropriately.

The document root for the websites should be under `/var/www` or `/srv/www`. This allows you to have tight security on the home directory tree.

Specify the full `DocumentRoot` for your virtual servers.

Check that you haven't enabled user directories for your virtual servers. These will walk the `/home` tree.

Comment: The reason I keep all of my Virtual hosts at my home directory /home/sultan/Web/...

Answer (score 0):

Try to `chmod 755 /home/www`
then do the same with "hostdirectory"

```
chmod 755 /home/www/hostdirestory
```